# MySQL select * but place array of ids to the bottom of the result

Tags: php, mysql

HI all ,

if i do a `select * from table` 
the output of `ID` column will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ... etc .

is there anyway i can do a `select * from table where id not in (3,6,9)` then a `select * from table where id in (3,6,9)` in one query so the output will be like
1,2,4,5,7,8,10 .... 3,6,9 ???

Thank you .

Edit :

`select * from table order by ts desc` then `select * from table where id in (3,6,9)` ?

Comment: re: Your Edit: Should it be? `select * from table where id not in (3,6,9) order by ts desc` then `select * from table where id in (3,6,9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
select * from table where id not in (3,6,9)
UNION ALL
select * from table where id in (3,6,9)
```

Comment: +1 For using `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` as I would have thought that with the latter there is every chance that a sort will occur to get rid of duplicates completely negating the exercise. I still think that this is dubious semantically however. A future version of the optimiser should be free to rewrite this expression as the semantically equivalent `select * from table where id is not null` as it says nothing about the desired final order and just relies on current implementation.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id in (3,6,9) THEN id ELSE 1 END
```

RE: Your Edit:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id in (3,6,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, ts DESC
```

Comment: ok assuming i am already ordering the table by another field (timestamp) , is there anyway to keep the order by timestamp , and then add the ids as they r ?

Comment: @Ronan, Do you mean that within each "section" you want the rows ordered by `timestamp`? If so you can use `ORDER BY CASE WHEN id in (3,6,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, timestamp` @Johan - `UNION` won't work. `UNION` will itself cause a sort to eliminate duplicates. `UNION ALL` will probably work but that is just relying on an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
select * from table where id not in (3,6,9)
union
select * from table where id in (3,6,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) query:

```
 SELECT ...
 UNION
 SELECT ...
```